# FAILED: SemanticException Column line_id Found in more than One Tables/Subqueries

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I got the following error while the running this hive script.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE foo_test PARTITION (ds='${DAY}')
SELECT dt1.time, dt1.line_id, dt1.foo_id, dt1.bar_code
FROM test_logs dt1
JOIN
    ( SELECT MIN(time) as foo_time, line_id, foo_id
      FROM test_logs
      WHERE ( ds >= '2015-02-10') AND ds <= '2015-02-16') AND line_id IN ('2609', '2610', '2763')
      GROUP BY line_id, foo_id ) dt2

ON dt1.time = dt2.foo_time
WHERE ( dt1.ds >= '2015-02-10') AND dt1.ds <= '2015-02-16') AND line_id IN ('2609', '2610', '2763')
```

How to I run this hive script without error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WHERE clause references `line_id`, which is ambiguous because it could either be from `dt1` or `dt2`. You will need to change it to either `dt1.line_id` or `dt2.line_id`, depending on which you intended to refer to.